# is it possible to read php file with file_get_contents?

Tags: php, security, include, file-get-contents, include-path

I created web page which load ( just `css,js`)from url get request.I have done this before with `include` but it is dangerous because hacker can include file which is not from `public_html`.I tried this on `file_get_contents` and it says bad request which is perfect but I want to be sure because actually I heard that `file_get_content`s is dangerous?I don't want to help hacker to read php file because I heard that it is possible with `file_get_contents`?

Comment: You can read **any** file with `file_get_contents` as long as the permissions are given. You should use a whitelist to compare against the requested file to make sure, only files you want to be read are going outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` may be dangerous if you use user supplied data as a parameter and print its output. A malicious user may then use e.g. `/etc/passwd` to read all your server's user names. Or, he/she could use '..' as part of the file name to access files even if you prepend the name with an allowed path (e.g. "../../etc/passwd")

To prevent that from happening, you should always check user given values for validity, for example, that a file name or path is in an expected part of your file system, and so accessing only files that you want the user to access. PHP has a function to make relative paths (or paths that contains symbolic links) 'real': [realpath()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php).

After making a path 'real' you can check the path if it is in the expected part of the file system and then safely use it for `file_get_contents()`.

```
$wanted = $_GET['path'];
$real = realpath('/var/www/user/accessible/' . $wanted);
if (strpos($real, '/var/www/user/accessible/') === 0) {
   echo file_get_contents($real);
} else {
   throw new Exception('not allowed to access this file');
}
```

Comment: okay it worked  but I want to be sure are there another way to track file_get_content and read file which is not in public_html?Also this method is not working on localhost because I echo $real it is E:\wamp64\www\website\public\css\fonts\google_fonts.css but it should be www/website/ (different is / and \).Is that can be problem?

Comment: Can I check it like if (trim($real) !='') {

}because it return empty if file contain ../
Is it always true?